# ValueError: The model expects 2 input arrays, but only received one array (Keras/Tensorflow)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to train a Keras model with the following model.fit line:

```
history = model.fit(imgs,ground_truths, batch_size=16, epochs=30, shuffle=True,
              validation_split=0.2,
              callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

Both have the shape `(2080, 256, 256, 3)` which is the correct input shape for the model.

However, for some reason, even though I am passing in 2 parameters, I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The model expects 2 input arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (2080, 256, 256, 3)
```

This is how I preprocess my images:

```
def preprocess(imgs):
    imgs_p = np.ndarray((imgs.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(imgs.shape[0]):

        arr = imgs[i]

        arr = arr.astype('float')
        arr /= 255.
        imgs_p[i] = resize(arr, (256, 256), preserve_range=True)

    return imgs_p
```

The preprocessed images are saved in numpy files after preprocessing:

```
np.save('imgs_train_preprocess.npy', imgs)
np.save('imgs_gt_train_preprocess.npy', ground_truths)
```

Before training, I load the numpy files like this before training:

```
imgs = np.load('imgs_cup_train_preprocess.npy')
ground_truths = np.load('imgs_orig_train_preprocess.npy')
```

This is my model.summary:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to
====================================================================================================
conv1_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 256, 256, 3)   0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu1_1 (Activation)             (None, 256, 256, 3)   0           conv1_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_2_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 258, 258, 3)   0           relu1_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv2D)                 (None, 256, 256, 64)  1792        conv1_2_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu1_2 (Activation)             (None, 256, 256, 64)  0           conv1_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling2D)             (None, 128, 128, 64)  0           relu1_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_1_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 130, 130, 64)  0           pool1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv2D)                 (None, 128, 128, 128) 73856       conv2_1_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu2_1 (Activation)             (None, 128, 128, 128) 0           conv2_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_2_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 130, 130, 128) 0           relu2_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv2D)                 (None, 128, 128, 128) 147584      conv2_2_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu2_2 (Activation)             (None, 128, 128, 128) 0           conv2_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool2 (MaxPooling2D)             (None, 64, 64, 128)   0           relu2_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_1_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 66, 66, 128)   0           pool2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv2D)                 (None, 64, 64, 256)   295168      conv3_1_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu3_1 (Activation)             (None, 64, 64, 256)   0           conv3_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_2_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 66, 66, 256)   0           relu3_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv2D)                 (None, 64, 64, 256)   590080      conv3_2_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu3_2 (Activation)             (None, 64, 64, 256)   0           conv3_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_3_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 66, 66, 256)   0           relu3_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_3 (Conv2D)                 (None, 64, 64, 256)   590080      conv3_3_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu3_3 (Activation)             (None, 64, 64, 256)   0           conv3_3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool3 (MaxPooling2D)             (None, 32, 32, 256)   0           relu3_3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_1_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 34, 34, 256)   0           pool3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv2D)                 (None, 32, 32, 512)   1180160     conv4_1_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu4_1 (Activation)             (None, 32, 32, 512)   0           conv4_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_2_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 34, 34, 512)   0           relu4_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv2D)                 (None, 32, 32, 512)   2359808     conv4_2_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu4_2 (Activation)             (None, 32, 32, 512)   0           conv4_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_3_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 34, 34, 512)   0           relu4_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_3 (Conv2D)                 (None, 32, 32, 512)   2359808     conv4_3_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu4_3 (Activation)             (None, 32, 32, 512)   0           conv4_3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool4 (MaxPooling2D)             (None, 16, 16, 512)   0           relu4_3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_1_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 18, 18, 512)   0           pool4[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2D)                 (None, 16, 16, 512)   2359808     conv5_1_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu5_1 (Activation)             (None, 16, 16, 512)   0           conv5_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_2_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 18, 18, 512)   0           relu5_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2D)                 (None, 16, 16, 512)   2359808     conv5_2_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu5_2 (Activation)             (None, 16, 16, 512)   0           conv5_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_3_zeropadding (ZeroPadding (None, 18, 18, 512)   0           relu5_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_3 (Conv2D)                 (None, 16, 16, 512)   2359808     conv5_3_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_2_16_zeropadding (ZeroPadd (None, 130, 130, 128) 0           relu2_2[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu5_3 (Activation)             (None, 16, 16, 512)   0           conv5_3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_2_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 16)  18448       conv2_2_16_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_3_16_zeropadding (ZeroPadd (None, 66, 66, 256)   0           relu3_3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_3_16_zeropadding (ZeroPadd (None, 34, 34, 512)   0           relu4_3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_3_16_zeropadding (ZeroPadd (None, 18, 18, 512)   0           relu5_3[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concat (InputLayer)              (None, 256, 256, 3)   0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsample2__zeropadding (ZeroPadd (None, 130, 130, 16)  0           conv2_2_16[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_3_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 16)    36880       conv3_3_16_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_3_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 16)    73744       conv4_3_16_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_3_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 16, 16, 16)    73744       conv5_3_16_zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
new-score-weighting (Conv2D)     (None, 256, 256, 1)   4           concat[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsample2_ (Conv2DTranspose)     (None, 262, 262, 16)  4112        upsample2__zeropadding[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsample4_ (Conv2DTranspose)     (None, 260, 260, 16)  16400       conv3_3_16[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsample8_ (Conv2DTranspose)     (None, 264, 264, 16)  65552       conv4_3_16[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsample16_ (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 272, 272, 16)  262160      conv5_3_16[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
sigmoid-fuse (Activation)        (None, 256, 256, 1)   0           new-score-weighting[0][0]
====================================================================================================
Total params: 15,228,804
Trainable params: 15,228,804
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The JSON architecture of the model is located here: https://pastebin.com/TE0Nda1p

Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide us with full `model.summary()`?

Comment: yes, I've updated the question.

Comment: Could you also show us the code of the model itself? It looks like you are trying to use 2 Inputs and concatenate them in "concat (InputLayer)" or is this a concatenation with the input itself (like in a residual block)?

Comment: @sladomic The model architecture is actually loaded from a json, but I have included at the bottom of the question as a pastebin link.

Comment: On line 2165 you can see, that both "conv1_1" and "concat" have been defined as input layers

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem when outputs=[a,b],change it to outputs=[a].

Answer (score 0):

Arrange model.fit arguments in i.e. [trainX, trainY], [trainY, trainX], and validation_data=([valX, valY], [valY, valX]), and verify the shapes of each set(train, val)
history = model.fit(
[trainX, trainY],[trainY, trainX],
batch_size=16,
epochs=1,
#validation_data=([valX, valY], [valY, valX]),
validation_split=0.2,
shuffle=False)